# how to make adjacency matrix for real location for SHARE model?

Tags: python, prediction, graph-neural-network, parking

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.10516.pdf this is the link for SHARE(Semi-Supervised Hierarchical Recurrent Graph Neural Network
for City-Wide Parking Availability Prediction).I think this code is useful for me but it doesnot have dataset. i want to predict the on-street parking availability and i have found lots of code that have dataset of  already preprocessed. I'm begginner in this field so i want to know what kind of adjacency matrix should i make and if anyone has material related to that process then it would be great help. I have data set of parking info （time, location, available space, total space, main street, 2 adjacency street, area, subarea, street code） and weather, and traffic as well .